# Opening encrypted realm db throws DecryptionFailed exception

Tags: realm

I have a very few amount of encrypted customer databases which cannot be opened by either the iOS- / Android-Sdk or the `MongoDB Realm Studio`. But they can be opened by `Realm Studio 5.0.3` without any problems.

When i open the database with `MongoDB Realm Studio`, a dialog appears after entering the key: "The Realm file stores data in an outdated format. This file needs to be upgraded to a newer file format before it can be opened. Would you like a backup of the file, before performing an irreversible upgrade of the file?". When i select "Backup and upgrade", the window stays empty.

The sdks and the `MongoDB Realm Studio` throw the following exception:

```
Update for version 11.1.1 is not available (latest version: 11.1.1, downgrade is disallowed).
(node:64733) electron: NSVisualEffectMaterialLight has been deprecated and removed as of macOS 10.15.
(node:64733) electron: NSVisualEffectMaterialLight has been deprecated and removed as of macOS 10.15.
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::util::DecryptionFailed: Decryption failed
Exception backtrace:
0   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107880e77 _ZN5realm4util16DecryptionFailedC2Ev + 103
1   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107867227 _ZN5realm4util10AESCryptor4readEixPcm + 519
2   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107867ede _ZN5realm4util20EncryptedFileMapping12refresh_pageEm + 110
3   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107868985 _ZN5realm4util20EncryptedFileMapping12read_barrierEPKvmPFmPKcE + 373
4   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x00000001072fb034 _ZN5realm4util26do_encryption_read_barrierEPKvmPFmPKcEPNS0_20EncryptedFileMappingE + 68
5   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x00000001072fae7b _ZN5realm5Array13init_from_refEm + 171
6   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x000000010776a2fd _ZN5realm11GroupWriterC2ERNS_5GroupENS_9DBOptions10DurabilityE + 765
7   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x00000001077650a3 _ZN5realm2DB16low_level_commitEyRNS_11TransactionE + 387
8   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107764ebb _ZN5realm2DB9do_commitERNS_11TransactionE + 107
9   .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107764116 _ZN5realm11Transaction6commitEv + 118
10  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x000000010776193d _ZN5realm2DB19upgrade_file_formatEbiii + 365
11  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x000000010775e9ad _ZN5realm2DB7do_openERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbbNS_9DBOptionsE + 4285
12  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107762039 _ZN5realm2DB4openERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 153
13  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x00000001077674c9 _ZN5realm2DB6createERNS_11ReplicationENS_9DBOptionsE + 265
14  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x00000001074b02df _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator7open_dbEv + 927
15  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x00000001074aef6a _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator12do_get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigERNSt3__110shared_ptrIS2_EENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEERNS8_17CheckedUniqueLockE + 58
16  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x00000001074aed5f _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator9get_realmENS_5Realm6ConfigENS_4util8OptionalINS_9VersionIDEEE + 495
17  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x000000010748dcd7 _ZN5realm5Realm16get_shared_realmENS0_6ConfigE + 135
18  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107316115 _ZN5realm2js10RealmClassINS_4node5TypesEE19create_shared_realmEN4Napi3EnvENS_5Realm6ConfigEbONSt3__13mapINS9_12basic_stringIcNS9_11char_traitsIcEENS9_9allocatorIcEEEENSA_ISG_NS0_9ProtectedINS5_5ValueEEENS9_4lessISG_EENSE_INS9_4pairIKSG_SJ_EEEEEESL_NSE_INSM_ISN_SQ_EEEEEEONSA_ISG_NSH_INS5_8FunctionEEESL_NSE_INSM_ISN_SW_EEEEEE + 245
19  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107315e85 _ZN5realm2js10RealmClassINS_4node5TypesEE11constructorEN4Napi3EnvENS5_6ObjectERNS0_9ArgumentsIS3_EE + 501
20  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107312ab5 _ZN5realm4node10ObjectWrapINS_2js10RealmClassINS0_5TypesEEEE20constructor_callbackERKN4Napi12CallbackInfoE + 149
21  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107315249 _ZN5realm4node13WrappedObjectINS_2js10RealmClassINS0_5TypesEEEEC2ERKN4Napi12CallbackInfoE + 121
22  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107315123 _ZZN4Napi10ObjectWrapIN5realm4node13WrappedObjectINS1_2js10RealmClassINS2_5TypesEEEEEE26ConstructorCallbackWrapperEP10napi_env__P20napi_callback_info__ENKUlvE_clEv + 67
23  .com.mongodb.realm-studio.6Lsjei    0x0000000107314e68 _ZN4Napi10ObjectWrapIN5realm4node13WrappedObjectINS1_2js10RealmClassINS2_5TypesEEEEEE26ConstructorCallbackWrapperEP10napi_env__P20napi_callback_info__ + 72
24  Electron Framework                  0x000000011974187b napi_is_detached_arraybuffer + 299
25  Electron Framework                  0x0000000113b23e65 _ZN2v88internal9Accessors12MakeAccessorEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_4NameEEEPFvNS_5LocalINS_4NameEEERKNS_20PropertyCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEEPFvS9_NS7_ISB_EERKNSA_INS_7BooleanEEEE + 21637
26  Electron Framework                  0x0000000113b21df9 _ZN2v88internal9Accessors12MakeAccessorEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_4NameEEEPFvNS_5LocalINS_4NameEEERKNS_20PropertyCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEEPFvS9_NS7_ISB_EERKNSA_INS_7BooleanEEEE + 13337
27  ???                                 0x0000001a00080ff8 0x0 + 111669678072
```

## Update 1

When i enter the wrong key in MongoDB Realm Studio (by changing the last digit of the key), i see a message on the screen that it is "Unable to open a realm at path ...". When i enter the correct key, the above exception happens.

## Update 2

When i open the database with `Realm Studio 5.0.3` i can view the data. As soon as i change a field (no matter which field), the "DecryptionFailed" exception appears in the console and `Realm Studio` crashes.

Comment: The current MongoDB Realm Studio (v11.1.1) should be able to open any prior file and migrate it to a current version. On the other hand v 5.0.3 only opens files and upgrades them to 5.0.3 - so it's curious why 5.0.3 could open the file at all. Is this a sync'd realm or local only?

Comment: These are local databases.